# How to extract text following a keyword in UNIX

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, text-extraction

I have a text file (`file.txt`) that contains a wall of results (no newlines, whitespaces etc) that I received from an external source.  From this file, I need to find all mentions of the word `serId`, and then print out the alpha-numeric sequence following it.  The alpha-numeric sequence is of any length but will end with the character `,`.  How can I extract these alpha-numeric sequences?

I've tried finding scripts/code using sed / awk but the results seem to revolve around a known sequence to find, rather than an unknown sequence.

For example, I would like to extract `28655784-EE` from the following sample text:

```
{"preRollbackCheckResults":[],"patchingHistory":[{"backupStatus":"Available","rollbackStatus":"Available","additionalNote":"Patching CDS as planned","appliedBy":"xxrbsgCDS02services","appliedDate":"2019-01-18T12:45:33.926+0000","totalTime":"29 min, 47 sec","serId":"28655784-EE","patchDescription":"DB 18.4.0.0.0 Oct 2018 PSU
```

Comment: provide sample input file. for unknown sequence you use RegEx matching. ask is the tool.

Comment: I'm using grep 2.20 and it appears to support the -o option. And a sample from the .txt file would be t
{"preRollbackCheckResults":[],"patchingHistory":[{"backupStatus":"Available","rollbackStatus":"Available","additionalNote":"Patching CDS as planned","appliedBy":"xxrbsgCDS02services","appliedDate":"2019-01-18T12:45:33.926+0000","totalTime":"29 min, 47 sec","serId":"28655784-EE","patchDescription":"DB 18.4.0.0.0 Oct 2018 PSU...            So what I would be trying to do is find "serId" in the file then extract "28655784-EE", that follows it.

Comment: I'm not sure but this looks like a `json` file, have you looked at `jq`?

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. The right solution is **NOT** to combine grep+awk as you seem to be heading for in your comments under the current grep and awk answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this awk script (gawk only):

```
awk  -F '","' 'match($0,/serId\":\"[^,]*/,m){print m[1]}' input.txt
```

If you need the terminating `,`

```
awk  -F '","' 'match($0,/serId\":\"[^,]*/,m){print m[1]","}' input.txt
```

explanation:

`-F ","` parse the file to records separated by `,`

`match($0,"serId[^,]*",m)` filter in current record, matching a string starting with `serId` terminating with `,`. Put result in array `m`

`print substr(m[0],8)` print the matched string from 8th position

Comment: This worked when I combined your solution with Dominique's.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I did but the upvote won't persist.  I don't know why?

Comment: Ah.  "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."  But I have upvoted.

Comment: The 2nd arg to match() is a regexp, not a string, so you should be using regexp `/` instead of string `"` delimiters, i.e. `match($0,/serId":"[^,]*/,..)` instead of `match($0,"serId\":\"[^,]*",..)`. `[^,]*` should really be `[^"]*` though and the whole point of using gawk for the 3rd arg to match() is to isolate the regexp segments as capture groups to reference in the action block so the code should really be `match($0,/serId":"([^"]*)/,m){print m[1]}` otherwise with any awk you can write `match($0,/serId":"[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8)}`

Comment: Thanks to @Ed Morton, updated with the recommendations.

Comment: You're welcome. You do need the parens to create the capture group though and you don't need to escape the double quotes inside `/`s  so use `/serId":"([^"]*)/` not `/serId\":\"[^,]*/`

Answer (score 1):

`grep -o` is a really easy solution for this:

I've created a file, containing following lines:

```
serId12345
serIdABCde123;
Ser_idblabla;
```

The first line does not end with a semi-colon, the third line starts with the wrong word, so only the second line is correct.

I've launched following command: `grep -o "serId[0-9a-zA-Z]*;" testtttt.txt`, with following result:

```
serIdABCde123;
```

Comment: This worked when I combined your solution with Dudi Boy's.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the short sample you posted in a comment, I have two suggestions:

- If the file is a well-formed [`json`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual), try to understand its structure and use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual).
- If it is malformed and can only be interpreted as a bunch of text, use the following Perl:

  ```
  perl -lne '@m=/"serId":"([^"]+)"/g; print "@m"' file.txt
  ```

  Test run:

  ```
  $ cat file.txt
  {"preRollbackCheckResults":[],"patchingHistory":[{"backupStatus":"Available","rollbackStatus":"Available","additionalNote":"Patching CDS as planned","appliedBy":"xxrbsgCDS02services","appliedDate":"2019-01-18T12:45:33.926+0000","totalTime":"29 min, 47 sec","serId":"28655784-EE","patchDescription":"DB 18.4.0.0.0 Oct 2018 PSU{"preRollbackCheckResults":[],"patchingHistory":[{"backupStatus":"Available","rollbackStatus":"Available","additionalNote":"Patching CDS as planned","appliedBy":"xxrbsgCDS02services","appliedDate":"2019-01-18T12:45:33.926+0000","totalTime":"29 min, 47 sec","serId":"28655784-EE","patchDescription":"DB 18.4.0.0.0 Oct 2018 PSU

  $ perl -lne '@m=/"serId":"([^"]+)"/g; print "@m"' file.txt
  28655784-EE 28655784-EE
  ```

---

Answer (score 0):

With any sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*"serId":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/' file
28655784-EE
```